# Get CGPoint when tap gesture event happens in iwatch

Tags: apple-watch, uitapgesturerecognizer, watchos

I want to add touch points and gestures in my Apple Watch app if possible.

I read that Apple Watch doesn't provide tap or swipe gesture recognition.

Is there any way to support tap gesture events, and determine `CGPoint` on the Apple Watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

watchOS 3 adds third-party support for gestures, including taps and swipes.

Your gesture recognizer action can monitor continuous touch tracking through the [`locationInObject()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkgesturerecognizer/1650823-locationinobject) method:

> Returns the point computed as the current position of the touch event.

You can find more information in the [`WKGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkgesturerecognizer) documentation, as well as the [WatchKit Catalog sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html).